# Can't get rid of tabs when pushing to login

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 app where when a user logs out, I want to push them to the login page.

However, when I push to that page I can't seem to get ride of the tabs.

I'm useing:

```
this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');
```

I've tried:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot.push('LoginPage');
```

and a few other things I've seen, but nothing works.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

In what page do you run `this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');` ? I'm guessing it is in one of your tab pages. (Side note: the argument for push is not a string, but a class.)

Instead of one of the tab pages, do this in `app.component.ts`.

```
this.nav.push(LoginPage);
```

or just use `setRoot`, but in `app.component.ts`

You will need to monitor the login status in `app.component.ts`, for which you can use a service or [RxJS `subject`](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/subjects.html)

Comment: That's the solution! The Problem (to explain it a little more) is, that you push the LoginPage on the NavStack **inside** the TabPage or in your second attempt you set the LoginPage as RootPage **for the TabsPage NavController**. You have to do this for the NavController in `app.component.ts` because this is the first NavController and there is the TabsPage set as rootPage.

Comment: Thing is, I'm trying to call it from a page called settings. How do you call a function in app.components.ts form an internal page?

Comment: You need some sort of shared variable or synchronization, which can be implemented by 1. global variable 2. Angular service 3. RxJS observable and subjects. 4. events. If you want to do a quick test, global variable is the fastest and easiest one, although not recommended by many programmers, and don't quote me on this. Just store the `nav` variable of `app.component` to a global variable and access it in  the other page.